# How to set border width with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two variables like this

```
var X = 200,
    Y = 100;
```

and i want to set the `boder-width` of an element with jQuery according to these variables. I tried something like

```
$('someElement'),css('border-width','X Y')

$('someElement'),css('border-width',X Y)

$('someElement'),css({borderWidth: X Y})
```

but none of the methods is worked. Any help?

Comment: $("element").css("border-width", x); should work. In your example you have ,css but need .css

Comment: Are X and Y pixel widths?

Comment: yes i is working but note that `X and Y` aren't same

Comment: border-width only takes one number

Comment: @CodeGodie no, you can do `border-width:100px 200px` with css

Comment: Really? I did not know that, i will test it out. In any case you need to do `.css`, not `,css`

Comment: Try: `$("someElement").css("border-width", X + "px " + Y + "px");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this i have added `px` and a space between X and Y

```js
var X = 200,
    Y = 100;
$('div').css('border-width',X+'px '+Y+'px');
```

```css
div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-color:green;
    border-style:solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: great,glad i could help @NafeesAnwar

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#someElement').css('border-width', X +'px'})
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, adding information about why this works will improve it's long-term value.